# How to get more than 10 search results from Yahoo Finance API?

Tags: json, ajax, rest, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

The following call will search the Yahoo Finance API for stocks that have "Yahoo" in its name:

```
http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=yahoo&region=US&lang=en-US&row=ALL&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback
```

Unfortunately, the result number is limited to 10 which causes problems for some search queries. Is there any way to increase the limit?

Comment: I searched a bit and tried a few things, but none of them worked on this API. Have you checked to the YQL API - https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console? The autocomplete seems to be in the pm.finance.autocomplete table.  It does require you to sign up and get an API key tho.

Comment: @tiblu There was an error in the url parameter "lang". It works now but it's still imited to 10 results :(

Comment: I did not find any way around the limit BUT YQL version of the API seems to support LIMIT and OFFSET.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How far back in time can I query historical quotes from Yahoo Finance YQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34233174/how-far-back-in-time-can-i-query-historical-quotes-from-yahoo-finance-yql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that the Yahoo Finance API is even a real thing. Read the article here: http://meumobi.github.io/stocks%20apis/2016/03/13/get-realtime-stock-quotes-yahoo-finance-api.html - the key takeaway is:

"It appears some have reverse engineered an API that they use to pull Finance data, but they are breaking our Terms of Service (no redistribution of Finance data) in doing this so I would encourage you to avoid using these webservices."

Other users on StackOverflow have reported similar issues with the services stopping altogether, or changing their behavior in an unannounced and undocumented way. Probably because the API isn't intended for public distribution. In fact, if it were, it would probably be really easy to find documentation. However, you can't find documentation because they haven't publicly released a public-facing API.

[Has Yahoo finance web service disappeared? API changed? Down temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355075/has-yahoo-finance-web-service-disappeared-api-changed-down-temporarily)

I think to accurately answer your question, I'd have to say: No, there's no way to get more than 10 results. You're already passing in "rows=ALL" - there's simply no more data exposed by the API.