# How far back in time can I query historical quotes from Yahoo Finance YQL?

Tags: yql, quantitative-finance

I'm building a small proof-of-concept app that requires historical stock quotes.  The UI in my app allows users to select a date range, and I've been using the YQL console to generate the REST calls to request the historical quote data.  YQL calls like this:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "JNJ" and startDate = "2015-01-01" and endDate = "2015-12-11"
```

work fine, but if I go too far back into time like this:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "JNJ" and startDate = "2013-01-01" and endDate = "2015-12-11"
```

I get no quotes back and find a warning in the XML that looks like this:

```
<warning>Too many instructions executed: 50223882</warning>
```

How far back in time can we query before running into the limit?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the limit for at least a single ticker quote is 364 records.  I found this out by doing several YQL queries and finding that this query works:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "JNJ" and startDate = "2014-07-03" and endDate = "2015-12-11"
```

and this one doesn't:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "JNJ" and startDate = "2014-07-02" and endDate = "2015-12-11"
```

When I parse the XML coming back from the first query, I find 364 records.